# Meaning of "werden" in this context

Tags: grammar, translation

In *Der Pfennig* by Hans Eckart, I've found the following sentence:

> Nach Jahren **wurde** er durch Fleiß und Eifer endlich **Vorarbeiter**.

If my understanding of the text is correct, this should mean: *After years of diligence and eagerness, he finally became a foreman*. [Textually, *through diligence and eagerness*].

That would mean that what we have here is the construction *werden + noun*, which translates into English as *to become something*.

Am I correct in my grammatical assumptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost.

"Werden" indeed translates to "become" here; your translation is entirely correct.

But I believe you meant to write *werden + noun* instead of *werden + adjective*. "Vorarbeiter"/"foreman" is a noun.

The construction with an adjective is also common, though:

> Er wird alt.
>
> Du bist groß geworden.
>
> Komm rein, das Essen wird kalt!

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's _werden + noun_. Already edited.

Comment: In that case, you are entirely correct in your grammatical assumptions.